# Convert Jquery slider to react file

Tags: jquery, reactjs, jquery-ui, react-props, react-state

Good day, Please I have been trying to get my slider bar function written in JQuery in my react app to filter through a number of dataset and display the result on the console. Please how can I do that

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a proper question and improve yours according the guidelines. As a first step, please add the code you already tried as a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and describe how it doesnt work for you. Were happy to help to find the problem, SO is not a coding service tho.

Answer (score 0):

You can make slider component, show and hide based on button toggle same like this https://codesandbox.io/s/5ku6t?file=/src/App.js